# Program terminated with signal 25, File size limit exceeded; why?

Tags: c++, c, linux

My program terminates with this error generating a core. The local disk wasnt full when I got this error. Error takes place from write() function.

My linux machine details are as follows,
Linux 2.6.18-274.18.1.el5 x86_64

I checked the ulimit -a and the details are as follows

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 1000000
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 49152
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 32
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 49152
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: What is your filesystem? Is your userland compiled with large file support?

Comment: FileSystem is ext3 and what did you mean by userland compiled with large file support?

Comment: @rkb, there is (was) a 2GB/4GB limit on file sizes that could only be removed by recompiling all the programs with large file support. It's pretty standard now, but you never know. As an aside, if your ext3 filesystem has a block size of 4KB, its maximum file size is 2TB. Maybe your disks are large enough for you to hit that limit?

Comment: Yes 2TB is much more that the local disk limit in my case. Also, recompiling all the programs with large file support is needed only in case of 32bit architecture. For 64 bit architect, I dont know if that is necessary as that flag only forces to use the 64bit variants for all file access.

Comment: whats the size of the file where it errors out? and what are you really asking? why it happens? or how to prevent it? or are you just wanting to tell someone that it happneed?

Comment: File size is less than 100GB. I am asking why it happens and how to prevent it.

Comment: @rkb 100GB would still be higher than the ext3 file size limit of 16GiB if block size is 1KiB. What block size do you use? (dumpe2fs might tell you if you don't know)

Comment: And what system? 32 or 64 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nabla is correct. The block size of 1KB which was causing the problem. Thanks for your help.